# "Train" a program to undistort a picture

Tags: opencv

I have a particular problem: I want to undistort pictures taken, that are always distorted the same way.

I imagine I could provide a correct image, and a distorted image and repeat some training process with for example 10-20 picture pairs. I will then use the resulting "transformation map" to undistort the pictures in the future.

Does opencv have the tools required to do this (which tools?) or should i look elsewhere (where?).

Comment: post sample images, I guess you don't mean lense distortion?

Comment: I have to come back with sample pictures in a week or so. I would like a system that takes any type of distortion. It could be simply perspective distortion, a "swirl"-effect, or a combination. Imagine taking a picture through a diamond. Then trying to "correct" the distortions based on prior training. Of course, taking a picture through a diamond would mean information would be lost but that is acceptable.